# vaex binary installation in windows

Tags: python, pandas, pip, conda, vaex

Installing Python packages can be as frustrating as it can be. Maybe I am the only poor pathetic who still stucks in Windows and the world is living their world happily in Mac and Linux

I am trying to install vaex in my venv environment in Windows. But I got the following unmovable enterprise obstacles:

1. pip install is not possible as I am unable to install the Visual C++ Build Tools which requires admin rights
2. Direct Git download or clone do require Visual C++ Build Tool
3. Conda only up-to version 4.3 which I am not allow to set the proxy when I try to use the conda-forge channel to install
4. Conda 4.3 is not accepting proxy server settings via command line. There is no way I am able to make conda to use .condarc file. The solution I was proposed is to upgrade to 4.4 which I am not able to do that
5. Other dependencies pop-up when I try to upgrade conda to 4.4. conda upgrade conda forces me into a whole list of packages that I need to upgrade/install along where I was given no choice to select *only* conda

Or alternatively, what can I do to compile all the required elsewhere and repackage the whole package for installation?

Comment: Do you have access to virtual machines (Virtualbox, Vmware, etc.)? Are you familiar with one of the free CI/CD offerings (Appveyor, Travis CI, Circle CI,etc.)?

Comment: @sinoroc not really but thanks for pointing out that alternative

Answer (score 1):

You could build the *wheel* distribution of this project (and all its dependencies) on another Windows machine of the same *bitness* (32 or 64 bits) and with same (minor) version of the Python interpreter. This *wheel* distribution can then be reused on the target machine.